# Dangling modifier

Tags: modifiers, dangling-modifier, dangling-participle

Is it correct to write -

*According to the conditions of my scholarship, after finishing my degree, the University will employ me.*

The university doesn't finish the degree. So if I write '**after finishing my degree, the University will employ me**', doesn't it misplace the modifier?

Comment: @WeatherVane But the university does not finish the degree. So if i write 'after finishing my degree, the university will employ me', doesn't it misplace the modifier?

Comment: The phrase "after finishing my degree" cannot apply to the university, because it is **my degree**.

Comment: The question has changed, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, new to this platform. Still learning. Should have created a new question instead of editing it and changing the question.

Comment: Welcome - please ask one question at a time!

Comment: @WeatherVane Got it.

Comment: To clarify:  Editing your question is fine (and encouraged) if you're adding more information, clarifying the intent, etc.  However, If your edits would essentially change it into a different question, it's usually better to create a new one (and possibly close the existing one if it's no longer relevant)..

Comment: "I went prospecting for gold and after finding a big nugget, Texas Pete shot me." These constructions can be ambiguous but nothing ungrammatical about it.

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't it misplace the modifier?

Yes, this looks like a dangling modifier. The reader can probably still understand what was intended since there's only one reasonable interpretation. Also, in speech rather than writing, the rules are more lax.

A better phrasing:

> According to the conditions of my scholarship, after I finish my degree, the University will employ me.

Comment: Alternately, one could also say "According to the conditions of my scholarship, after finishing my degree, I will be employed by the University."

Answer (score 0):

According to the conditions of my scholarship, the University will employ me **after I finish my degree.**

is really the simplest solution here. Why have so many moving parts when they are not necessary??

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native but I would say that one doesn't finish a degree but you finish a course at college. I see natives didn't have a problem understanding the idea of getting a college diploma but if you think about it finishing college sounds more natural than finishing a degree or even finishing university.